# Putty (SSH) browser plugin?

Tags: windows, putty

Are there any SSH plugins for browsers?  I'm getting to the point where I'd like to be able to tab through some SSH sessions in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a solution to have PuTTy with multiple tabs, you should check out [Putty Connection Manager](http://puttycm.free.fr/cms/). I'm not aware of any SSH browser plugins.